# How do I connect the SQL Server database to my e-mail system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.net.mail

Having troubles with connecting my database to my email system. I have set up a database connection and a `SqlDataSource` connection, however I am unsure how to reference it on my aspx.cs page as I want to send an email to the email stored in the database.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="emailresult" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:databaseconnection %>' 
     SelectCommand ="SELECT [ID], [email], [role] FROM [emailtest]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

protected void EmailTestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.To.Add("");
        mailMessage.To.Add("");
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("studiodefault@hotmail.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = "Scrum Management Studio - Role Confirmation";
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.Body = "Hello, <br /><br /> You have been assigned the role of <b>[ROLE]</b>  <br /><br /> \n\nKind Regards, <br />The Scrum Management Studio Team" ;
        mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High; 
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp-isp.com");
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        Response.Write("Email has been successfully sent");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Could not send the email - error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: THINK THINK THINK: You can write a method that returns a string(email) from the database and use it in your new MailAddress(stringreturned);

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on here? Read the email address -> set it in the MailAddress -> send the email.

Comment: You are not helping!

Answer (score 1):

You may convert the "emailresult" SqlDataSource to DataTable and query from there

```
var dt = ((DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)).Table;
var emails = from e in dt.AsEnumerable()
                where e.Field<int>("ID") == 1
                select e.email;

foreach (var email in emails)
{
    mailMessage.To.Add(email);
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Just a basic programmer starting off.

Comment: Modified the code to match the select statement you have on the datasource. Make sure you have using System.Linq on top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already commented, you have to split what you want to do in separate parts:

1. Get the email address from your database
2. Send the email. (already there)

So, what you want to find out it how to get email from you sqldatasource, which will be something like this (not tested):

```
DataView dv = emailresult.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();
String Email = Convert.ToString(dt.rows[0]["Email"]);
```